# discord.py выдача ролей по реакции

Tags: python, discord.py, role

Написал классическую выдачу роли по реакции. Никакой ошибки нет, но роли не выдаёт. Все права были выданы.

Код:

```
#выдача ролей по реакциям
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    messageid = payload.message_id
    if messageid == 979979550899454022: #id сообщения
        if payload.emoji == '':
            role = discord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=976819294623109140) #id роли
            await payload.member.add_roles(role, reason='новоприбывший нажал на реакцию')
```

Comment: Просто начните построчно интерпретировать код в голове и заметите, что вы сравниваете `id` сообщения с `id` канала: `messageid = payload.channel_id`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в этих строках

```py
messageid = payload.channel_id
if messageid == 979979550899454022: #id сообщения
```

`payload.channel_id` - это канал, в котором реагируется эмодзи. Вы же каналу придаёте id сообщения, измените код на:

```py
messageid = payload.message_id
if messageid == 979979550899454022:
```

Comment: Спасибо, скорее всего, это одна из причин, НО, к сожалению, функция выдачи роли так и не заработала. В любом случае спасибо, так как сам бы я не заметил такую деталь

Comment: Возможно, ошибка в строке ```role = discord.utils.get(payload.member.guild.roles, id=976819294623109140)```. Измените payload.member.guild.roles на guild.roles а до этого введите переменную guild = bot.get_guild(id сервера)